# NodeMCU MQTT getting topic but not calling IF loop

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I am very new to Arduino/ESP and I am writing a code to activate 2 relays using MQTT. My connection is successful and I am able to receive message/topic printed out on serial console. Here is my code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <DNSServer.h>
#include <WiFiManager.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "SSD1306Wire.h"
#define wifi_ssid "SSID"
#define wifi_password "PASSWORD"
#define mqtt_server "192.168.1.1"
#define mqtt_user "mqtt_username"
#define mqtt_password "mqtt_password"

SSD1306Wire  display(0x3c, D2, D1); 
const int relay1 = 5;
const int relay2 = 4;
String header;
String output5State = "off";
String output4State = "off";
const int output5 = 5;
const int output4 = 4;
WiFiClient wificlient;
WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);
ESP8266WebServer server(80);

//------------------- MAIN WEB PAGE ------------------------
const char MAIN_page[] PROGMEM = R"=====(
<head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<title>HOME IOT</title>
<style>html { font-family: Helvetica; display: inline-block; margin: 0px auto; text-align: center;}
.button { background-color: #195B6A; border: none; color: white; padding: 16px 40px
text-decoration: none; font-size: 30px; margin: 2px; cursor: pointer
body{margin-top: 50px;} h1 {color: #444444;margin: 50px auto 30px;
.button2 {background-color: #77878A;
p {font-size: 24px;color: #444444;margin-bottom: 10px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="webpage">
<h1>Security Door</h1>
<p><a href="/show/SecurityDoor/Open"><button class="button">Open</button></a></p>
<p><a href="/show/SecurityDoor/Close"><button class="button">Close</button></a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
)=====";
//------------------- MAIN WEB PAGE ------------------------

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  setup_wifi();
  client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
  client.setCallback(callback);
  //-----------------------------------------
  WiFiManager wifiManager;
  //wifiManager.resetSettings();
  wifiManager.autoConnect("IOT-LivinRoom");
  //-----------------------------------------
  server.on("/", handle_OnConnect);
  server.onNotFound(handle_NotFound);
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Initializing OLED Display");
  display.init();

  display.flipScreenVertically();
  display.setFont(ArialMT_Plain_10);
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}


void setup_wifi() {
  delay(10);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(wifi_ssid);
  WiFi.begin(wifi_ssid, wifi_password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

}


void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  Serial.print("Message arrived [");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print("] ");
  String messageTemp;
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
    messageTemp += (char)payload[i];
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print(messageTemp);


 if(topic=="livingroom/securitydoor"){
     Serial.print("Changing esp01 relay1 to ");
     if(messageTemp == "on"){
       digitalWrite(relay1, LOW);
       Serial.print("On");
       Serial.print("On from opening");   

     }
     else if(messageTemp == "off"){
       digitalWrite(relay1, HIGH);
       Serial.print("Off");
       Serial.print("On from Closing");
     }
 }
 Serial.println();

 if(topic=="livingroom/ac"){
     Serial.print("Changing esp01 relay2 to ");
     if(messageTemp == "on"){
       digitalWrite(relay2, LOW);
       Serial.print("On");
       Serial.print("On from opening");


     }
     else if(messageTemp == "off"){
       digitalWrite(relay2, HIGH);
       doorClosing();
       Serial.print("Off");
       Serial.print("On from Closing");
     } 
 }
 Serial.println();
}

void reconnect() {
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    if (client.connect("ESP8266Client", mqtt_user, mqtt_password)) {
      Serial.println("connected");
      client.subscribe("livingroom/securitydoor");
      client.subscribe("livingroom/ac");
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

//--------------------------- void loop----------------------- 
void loop() {

  server.handleClient();
  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
  client.loop();

}

//----------------------------- Web Calls Function -----------
void handle_OnConnect() {
String s = MAIN_page; //Read HTML contents
server.send(200, "text/html", s);
}

void handle_NotFound(){
  server.send(404, "text/plain", "Not found");
}
```

Issue is: message from below is not printing in serial

```
       Serial.print("On");
       Serial.print("On from opening");
```

In fact code is displaying topic and message in serial console.

My actual user case is to display status on OLED display as well as control relay.

Comment: That's not how you compare C strings.  You're comparing two addresses there, and they will never match.  Read up on `strcmp`.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for suggestions,

When i am doing it in below way, it got worked

```
if (strcmp(topic, "livingroom/securitydoor") == 0)
  {
    Serial.print(topic);
  }
```